# how to select floating graphics in word using keyboard shortcut?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2007, vbscript

In MS Word, floating graphical objects such as these are considered to be on a different layer above the "page" where the text stays:

[image]

However, to select these floating object I need to manually click them form the mouse. Is it possible to somehow go into the floating graphics layer so that I can select all graphics on that layer (on a current page) using keyboard shortcut such as ctrl+a?

If there is a vbscript that will select all floating graphics on a page for me, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a keyboard shortcut but a workaround - zoom out the page so you can see all your objects, and then select `Home` > `Editing` > `Select` > `Select Objects` (i.e. Alt-H SL O).  Then you can select all objects by selecting an area with the mouse.

Comment: This is actually close enough to what I need. Thank you very much. By the way, is this option available in older versions of word?

Comment: What version are you referring to?

Comment: As far as I can remember, there is an icon that looks like ordinary cursor arrow, in the drawing toolbar of Word 2003.

Answer (score 0):

> Applies to MS Word 2007, might work on upper versions, didn't tried.

You can assign custom keyboard shortcut to select all objects in the active window

Office button > Word options > Customize > Keyboard shortcuts: Customize > Categories: All commands > Commands: DrawSelectAll

Cheers.